# Examples of operators like multi body fermions in finite potential well with total energy being sum of energies, and not entirely homogeneous

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, operators

I'm looking for examples of systems with operators like the 2 fermion system in finite potential well where the total energy

$\lambda(k) = \lambda_1(k) + \lambda_2(k)$

where $k$ is the depth of the well. In addition to this I'm looking for some interaction between them causing non-homogenity, like here

the first electron occupies the ground state and the second electron is not in bound state for $k< k_c$. But for $k>k_c$, first electron in in ground state and second in in second bound state.

So $\lambda(k) = \lambda_1(k)$ for $k<k_c$ and $\lambda(k) = \lambda_1(k) + \lambda_2(k)$ for $k>k_c$.